# How to get a hash table or record type in Javascript without any name space collision?

Tags: javascript, hashmap

In JavaScript it is common to use objects as hashes:

```
hash = {};
hash.key = 'value';
```

It is even possible to use keys with spaces:

```
hash['a key'] = 'a value';
```

But there are several limitations: a key must not be called

- `__proto__`,
- `constructor`,
- `hasOwnProperty`,
- `isPrototypeOf`,
- `propertyIsEnumerable`,
- `toLocalString`,
- `toString`,
- `valueOf`,
- `__defineGetter__`,
- `__defineSetter__`,
- `__lookupGetter__`,
- `__lookupSetter__`,

because this will cause a name space collision with the internals of JavaScript objects.

What is the best work around to circumvent this limitation?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.create` and set parent as `null`, for example

```js
var data = {};
console.log( 
  data.toString
); // in parent prototype there is toString method. returns function 

var hash = Object.create(null);
console.log( 
  hash.toString,
  hash.valueOf,
  hash.__defineGetter__
); // will be undefined because we set parent as null
```